# How to rearrange the out-of-order data to sequential data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I know that Apache IoTDB can efficiently handle out-of-order data by rearranging them to sequential data. I wonder what is the command for reordering these out-of-order data in Apache IoTDB, so I can execute this command in my system?

Answer (score 0):

Apache IoTDB will automatically eliminate out-of-order data files and switch it to sequential data by built-in algorithm on a regular basis, therefore you do not need to execute certain command to do this.